# CSRF в django

Tags: python, django

Изучаю формы по мануалу джанги, следую строго по инструкции:

1.Добавляю {% csrf_token %} в форму

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Получаю

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

2.В гугле предлагают закомментировать 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', чего не хотелось бы. Либо добавить во [view.py](http://view.py):

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    name = "MakcuM"
     age = 28
    return render_to_response("template.html", c)
```

Вопрос в том, как в этом случае в шаблон `template.html` передать не только словарь с, но и нужные мне данные (в примере `name` и `age`).

Буду признателен за ответ или за ссылку на источник. Спасибо.

Comment: {% csrf_token %} является тегом шаблонов Django, такое действие c.update(csrf(request)) я никогда не выполнял, тег просто работает в шаблоне…

Comment: Также {{ csrf_token }} просто выведет в шаблоне значение токена…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c.update({'data': value})
```

или

```
c.update(name='MakcuM', age=28)
```

Answer (score 3):

Используй `RequestContext`,
например:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```