# Как и зачем используется RequestContext?

Tags: python, django

В продолжении темы RequestContext.

Привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, в доках сказано, что RequestContext добавляет группу переменных в контекст шаблона, следющим образом:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    return {'name': 'Влад', 'nick': 'johniek_comp', 'age': 17}

def myView(request):
    return render_to_response('template.html', {}, context_instanse=RequestContext(request, processors = [custom_proc[))
```

А в ответе, который вы мне [прислали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134237#134282) не было парамента processors

```
def index(request):
    render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Как в этом случае (т.е. зачем) используется RequestContext?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[RequestContext](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/ref/templates/api.html#django.template.RequestContext) - класс, который собирает все используемые обработчики контекста `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` из настроек и переданные на прямую через переменную из текущего вопроса (не обязательную) и возвращает результат их исполнения в виде словаря. Обычно создание этого класса вставляют в вызов рендера, что автоматически передаёт словарь с переменными в вызов…